# cppcheck in SublimeLinter doesn't work

Tags: sublimetext2, cppcheck

I'm new to sublime text and I'm stuck with a problem - I installed [SublimeLinter](https://github.com/SublimeLinter/SublimeLinter) via [Package Control](http://wbond.net/sublime_packages/package_control), and installed cppcheck via `sudo apt-get install cppcheck` (I'm using linux mint 13). SublimeLinter works fine with python source code, but don't show any vital signs when I save/load .cpp files and ask to show lint errors in C++ source code. What am I doing wrong?

UPD

Here is my sublime text console output:

```
...
SublimeLinter: c_cpplint loaded
SublimeLinter: C loaded
...
SublimeLinter: c enabled (using "cppcheck" for executable)
SublimeLinter: python enabled (built in)
...
```

Shall I set up support for .cpp code manually?